# I couldn't figure out the MVC Logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Entity is:

```
public partial class Persons
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string? Name { get; set; }

public string? Surname { get; set; }

public string? Number { get; set; }

public string? Address { get; set; }

public string? PublicId { get; set; }

public string? FatherName { get; set; }

public string? MotherName { get; set; }
```

}

Also Model is:

```
public partial class OnlyPrivateProp
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string? Name { get; set; }

public string? Surname { get; set; }
}
```

And controller:

```
 public class DemoController : Controller
 {
    _context c;

    public DemoController(_context c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ET model= new ET();
        var select = ..............



        return View();
    }
}
```

I dont want to use all data to display only three colunms. So I defined a model has three prop. But I cant pass data to model and cant select data and cant send controller.

Comment: Please update with actual code you have tried and the specific challenge you have with that.

Comment: Create a view model, query the 4 columns and bind it to the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create different ViewModel for different Views

The entities models  are mapped to the tables in your database,you could check the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/) related with EFCore

For your requirement,you could fill the viewmodel and pass the value to your View as below:

```
[Table("SomeTable")]
    public class SomeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
        ...........

    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }

    }

public IActionResult SomeAction()
        {

            ...........
            var vmlist = _context.SomeEntity.Select(x => new ViewModel{ Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop3 = x.Prop3 }).ToList();

            return View(vmlist);
        }
```

And the [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#pass-data-to-views) related with MVC

Comment: var vmlist = _context.SomeEntity.Select(x => new ViewModel{ Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop3 = x.Prop3 }).ToList();
At this section; don't we  use the whole table for the four columns?

var vmlist = _context.SomeEntity.Where(p=>p.Prop1).....tolist();  Same ?

Comment: refer the package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug and check the document,you could check the sql string when you  debug,I'm going to have arest,I'll update the detailed steps tomorrow